# how to make caption and label

Tags: tables

[image: .]

```
\caption{Tabel penugasan bilangan tegas (\textit{crips}) PT. KSM}
\label{T2}
\begin{center}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
    & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 1.67  & 2.33  & 3.67  & 2     \\
    J_2 & 2.67  & 2.67  & 2.89  & 2     \\
    J_3 & 1.33  & 2.33  & 3.33  & 2.33  \\
    J_4 & 3.33  & 1.33  & 2.67  & 1     \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz{
    \node (f) [draw, inner xsep=0.7em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(2-2) (5-5)] {};
        }
    \end{NiceMatrix}$
\end{center}
```

1. how to make caption and label for this table, when I run this algorithm, I have an error in \caption and \label.
2. how equalize the table lines, so that the rows and columns M_ij and J_ij have the same width

Comment: As always on this site please post full but minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. `\caption` needs a floating env around it and you do not snow any.

Comment: If you use for your code fragment  code from my answers on your previous questions, then now is time, that you accept these answers (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answers).

Answer (score 2):

Let me reuse my answer on yours first question, with following changes:

- used is `article` document class
- image is put in `figure` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{Tabel penugasan bilangan tegas (\textit{crips}) PT. KSM}
\label{T2}
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
        & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \node (f) [draw, inner xsep=1em, fit=(2-2) (5-5)] {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, opacity=0.2]
        (2-2 |- f.north) -- (5-2 |- f.south)
        (3-2 -| f.west)  -- (3-5 -| f.east)
        (5-2 -| f.west)  -- (5-5 -| f.east);
     }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
    \end{figure}
See figure \ref{T2} ...
\end{document}
```